# How to write tests for Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient?

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, tornado

I'm trying to follow TDD practice while writing Tornado application. I have an endpoint with `get` method which get data from several API's, filter, combine it and send a response. For this `get` handler I created a helper, which is responsible for async data fetching. And I want to write tests for it.

Helper looks like this:

```
class DummyHelper(object):
    @gen.coroutine
    def fetch(self, url):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch(url)

        raise gen.Return(response.body)
```

And tests are:

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from tornado.web import HTTPError
import app
from lib.handlers.dummy import DummyHelper
from tornado.testing import gen_test

class TestDummyHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):    
    def get_app(self):
        return app.get_app()

    @gen_test
    def test_200_fetch(self):
        helper = DummyHelper()
        response = yield helper.fetch("http://google.com/")
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)

    @gen_test
    def test_404_fetch(self):
        helper = DummyHelper()
        with self.assertRaises(HTTPError):
            yield helper.fetch("http://google.com/test")
```

Everything works fine for `test_200_fetch`. But it's not working for `test_404_fetch`. How to make it work? And should I even write those tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is against different exception. There are two `HTTPError`

- [`from tornado.web import HTTPError`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L2062) used in `RequestHandler` - exception that will turn into an HTTP error response,
- [`from tornado.httpclient import HTTPError`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py#L595) raised by `AsyncHTTPClient` on http errors

You need to use the one from httpclient.

**Hint**

1. if you are not testing `RequestHandler` you can use `AsyncTestCase`, it does not require `get_app`
2. if your tests depends on external resource (google..com), cannot be easily isolated... this is not a unit test, more integration one. This is not a bad thing, but it is worth to note.

**Example**

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient


class DummyHelper(object):
    @gen.coroutine
    def fetch(self, url):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
        raise gen.Return(response)


import unittest
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPError
from tornado.testing import gen_test

class TestDummyHandler(AsyncTestCase):

    @gen_test
    def test_200_fetch(self):
        helper = DummyHelper()
        response = yield helper.fetch("http://google.com/")
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)

    @gen_test
    def test_404_fetch(self):
        helper = DummyHelper()
        with self.assertRaises(HTTPError):
            yield helper.fetch("http://google.com/test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you write a piece of code how to handle 404 for `DummyHelper.fetch`. I'm trying to implement what you mentioned but it still fails.

Comment: I've added some example